# how to find number of open jdbc connections to sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, jdbc

At any point in time when my application is running I would like to know how many open jdbc connections are there (SQL Server)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: This will give you all current processes:

```
USE master;
GO
EXEC sp_who;
GO
```

Please see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174313.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT 
  DB_NAME(dbid) as DBName, 
  COUNT(dbid) as NumberOfConnections,
  loginame as LoginName,
  program_name as 'Program Name'
FROM
  sys.sysprocesses
WHERE 
  dbid > 0 AND program_name LIKE '%jdbc%'
GROUP BY 
  dbid, loginame,program_name
```

The above will give you the number of JDBC Connections for each database.

Use this if you just want the total:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(dbid) as NumberOfConnections
FROM
  sys.sysprocesses
WHERE 
  dbid > 0 AND program_name LIKE '%jdbc%'
```

Comment: This would only work if the program name does contain the string "jdbc". JDBC client applications may identify themselves under any name.

Comment: @Ralf Usually the Official JDBC Drivers will be identified correctly. Something like `Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server` will be returned

Comment: I don't know about the default for the MS driver. We always set the attribute `applicationName` to be able to identify the connecting application. The default for the i-Net Merlia drivers is "i-Net Merlia" as application name.